# I need to rewrite url with regex in .htaccess file for cra web app

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I was create an app with create-react-app. Set all routes with react router dom v6. These are all English pathnames but I need to convert them to Turkish. I used regex rewrite like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /b2b/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product-list$ urun-listesi [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ anasayfa [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^account-prop$ firma-bilgileri [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^account-statement$ hesap-ekstresi [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^basket$ sepet [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cargo-info$ kargo-bilgisi [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cargo-detail$ kargo-detayi [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^claim-for-refund$ iade-basvurusu [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^compare-prods$ urunleri-karsilastir [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^credit-card-commisions$ kredi-karti-komisyonlari [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cas$ cari-hesap-ekstresi [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^e-payment$ e-odeme [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.html [QSA,L]
```

it works and convert pathname but then I get 404 error and page not upload. How to fix this?

I tried get static path but I really don't know how regex works so I failed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, do the turkish resources exist? If not you also need to take care to handle incoming requests to those again by means of an internal rewrite rule:

An example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /b2b/
RewriteRule ^product-list$ urun-listesi [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^urun-listesi$ product-list [L]
```

Comment: I write turkish words like example in question. Then url changing but i got " Uncaught TypeError: c.map is not a function " error in " main.f0176ce0.js:2 "

Comment: @MustafaCanDemir That does not sound like an issue with rewriting, on protocol level, but with your application logic. Did you understand what the error message actually says? I have no idea about your code, so that is nothing i can help with, sorry.